# Magento2.2.6 : How to maintain different quantities for different websites in multi website?

Tags: magento2.2.6, quantity

I am working on Magento-2.2.6.

I created two websites for our two stores under single Magento installation. That means, i am working on Multple websites under same Magento installation

In this, i can able to maintain the price and availability individually for each website.

But, we are maintaining two different quantity suppliers for each website.

I have modified price scope from Global to website in scope under

```
admin > stores > configuration > catalog > catalog > price > website in scope
```

As of now, Qty field's scope is as **Global**, But as per my requirement, Qty field's scope must be as **website**.

So, **How to manage the different quantity for each website's products?**

I have searched a lot for this but didn't get any proper solution for this qty to change from global to website in scope. But, not yet get the response. And that is global field in admin. we can't modify that, Need some customization.

Comment: price is on global scope in vanilla magento2. why not choose the same solution for inventory?

Comment: so. why not change the scope of qty to website? if you have done that with price you can do it with qty too. I would recommend excessive testing when doing such mayor changes

Comment: how did you do it for the price?